# How to implement and call a function with another function as an optional argument (filter function)

Tags: python, filter

I'm trying to write a function with a function as an optional argument. I want to use the second function as a filter function

```
def func1(arg1, arg2, func2, arg4=None):
    # do something with args1,2
    # do something with arg4 if called
    # do something with func2 if called

def func2(arg5):
    # do something

func1(41, "hello there")
```

In the example above I haven't called func2 . I know I could use a decorator i.e.

```
def func1(arg1, arg2, func2, arg4=None):
    # do something with args1,2
    func2()
    # do something with arg4 if called

def func2(arg5):
    # do something

func1(41, "hello there")
```

I'm not sure how to implement or call an optional decorator though. I think the best way would be to make the argument to func2 an argument in func1, `func1(arg1,arg2,arg5=None,arg4=None)` and then in func1 I could have some logic like this:

```
def func1(arg1, arg2, arg5=None, arg4=None):
    # do something with args1,2
    if arg5 is not None:
        func2(arg5)
    # do something with arg4 if called

def func2(arg5):
    # do something

func1(41, "hello there")
```

Any suggestions would be much appreciated!

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding the question here. I recommend using real syntax. You refer to decorators but I don't see any. Can you clarify what you need?

Comment: In your first example `func2` is not an optional parameter calling without it would produce an Exception.

Comment: `... I haven't called func2...` -> you haven't *passed* `func2`.  https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#more-on-defining-functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some coding errors pointed out above in comments about code structure need to be fixed.  Optional arguments are created by providing a default value.  Something like this should get you by:

```
In [1]: def print_result(x, f=None): 
   ...:     if f: 
   ...:         x = f(x) 
   ...:     print("the final answer is: %i" % x) 
   ...:                                                                         

In [2]: def doubler(x): 
   ...:     return x*2 
   ...:                                                                         

In [3]: print_result(5)                                                         
the final answer is: 5

In [4]: print_result(5, doubler)                                                
the final answer is: 10
```

Comment: I probably shouldn't have mentioned the decorator nor posted the question via mobile!